# jQuery first click addClass, second click redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a temporary (and fake) form validation.

On the form, if you click submit the first time, it adds a class of ".error" and a span to the required inputs. If you click submit again, I want it to redirect to another page.

I can't seem to figure out how to have two different functions on the same submit button. The first click needs to add a class, the second click should redirect.

Here's my code:

```
if($("button").hasClass('redirect')){
    $("button").click(function(){
        window.location.href="index.html";
    });
} else {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("redirect");
        $("input:required").addClass('error');
        $("<small class=error>Invalid entry.</small>").insertAfter("input:required");
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? Add it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('redirect'))
     {
        $(this).addClass("redirect");
        $("input:required").addClass('error');
        $("<small class=error>Invalid entry.</small>").insertAfter("input:required");
     }
     else
     {
        window.location.href="index.html";
     }
  });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should just use the same function? something like that :

```
$("button").click(function(){
    if($("button").hasClass('redirect')){
        window.location.href="index.html";        
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("redirect");
        $("input:required").addClass('error');
        $("<small class=error>Invalid entry.</small>").insertAfter("input:required");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("button").click(function(){
        if($("button").hasClass('redirect')){
            window.location.href="index.html";
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("redirect");
            $("input:required").addClass('error');
            $("<small class=error>Invalid entry.</small>").insertAfter("input:required");
        }
    });
```